# Can't deploy task set in AWS ECS using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

My main goal is to simply run a docker displaying a simple hello-world web on an instance and expose it to the internet using ECS auto-scaling & load balancer using terraform.

I have almost everything ready but it seems like the TASKS (supposed to be 2 running) won't deploy.
A service is configured and deployed successfully but without any task.
I try to create an `aws_ecs_task_set` resource but it **gives me an error:**

`"error creating ECS TaskSet: empty output"`

This is how my cluster looks on AWS (without any running-task or registered instance which I should have one)
[image_cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pirvm.png)

This is the `aws_ecs_service` I have configured:

```
    resource "aws_ecs_service" "scale" {
      name = "test"
      cluster = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs.id
      desired_count = 2
      task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.service.arn
      scheduling_strategy = "REPLICA"
      launch_type = "EC2"
    
      load_balancer {
        target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.foo.arn
        container_name = "first"
        container_port = 80
      }
    }
```

Task definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "service" {
  family = "service"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([     
   {       
      name      = "first"
      image     = "hello-world"
      cpu       = 1
      memory    = 512
      essential = true       
      portMappings = [         
       {
         containerPort = 80
         hostPort      = 80
       }       
      ]     
    },   
  ])    
  task_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::753392824297:role/segev-role-ecs"
}
```

this is the `aws_ecs_task_set` I have configured:

```
    resource "aws_ecs_task_set" "testing" {
      service = aws_ecs_service.scale.id
      cluster = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs.id
      task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.service.arn
      launch_type = "EC2"
      network_configuration {
        subnets = [module.networking.subnetp, module.networking.subnetp2]
        security_groups = [module.networking.sgid]
        assign_public_ip = true
      }
```

**This is how it should look like at the end**
[image_cluster2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXo7j.png)

Any idea how can I run these task?

Why does terraform gives me this error I mentioned above?

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Also the task definition would be good to see so please add it to the question.

Comment: @MarkoE

`resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "service" {
  family = "service"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name      = "first"
      image     = "hello-world"
      cpu       = 1
      memory    = 512
      essential = true
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 80
          hostPort      = 80
        }
      ]
    },
  ])
   task_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::753392824297:role/segev-role-ecs"

}`

That is the task definition.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that I can't even run a task through the AWS gui.
It says: No Container Instances were found in your cluster.
and it might have impact, I believe?

Comment: I'd start be defining the container registry where image is located insted of only `hello-world`.

Comment: @MarkoE
I tried changing the "hello-world" to the URL of the image which is stored on docker-hub and it didn't work.
Any other idea? Notice that I can't even run a task using the GUI because I get an error no container instances were found in your cluster.

Comment: It seems you have to follow the steps here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html.

Comment: @xshonlevix Did you get any solution for this, I am also facing a similar issue. Getting the same error while creating the task-set using terraform